# How to ask for "one of those" in a store

Tags: expressions

Imagine that you are in a store, perhaps a boulangerie, and want to buy an item, which you are not sure how to describe. In english I would say:

*"Can I get one of those, please"?*

Similarly, when in the cafeteria, I often want to ask the staff for e.g. some vegetables or sauce, which I may not be sure how to describe, and would say:

*"Can I get some of that, please?"*

How would you say this in French? My guesses would be:
*"Est-ce que je pourrais avoir l'un de ceci" or*
*"Est-ce que je pourrais en avoir un"*

or

*"Est-ce que je pourrais un peu de cela/ceci"*

I have been told that it is incorrect to say "un de ça" and that "de cela/ceci" is better, however I am very unsure whether this is true. Your comments and tips are very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would use *un peu* if the product is sold by volume/weight:

> Je peux avoir un peu de ça ?

For individual products, an informal question would be:

> Je peux [en] avoir un comme ça ?

or, informally:

> Je peux avoir un truc comme ça ?

or simply, showing the item with your finger:

> Je peux en avoir un ?

Comment: Thanks, your answers are very helpful! I will try out your suggestions :-)

Answer (score 0):

"Est-ce que je pourrais avoir l'un de ceci" won't do, whatever the case; "Est-ce que je pourrais avoir l'un de **ceux-ci**" is a possibility, although not usual, and the pronunciation is exactly the same. However, what you are asking for must be that type of thing available as units: buns, doughnuts, pastries, pieces of meat, whole fried chickens, chicken legs, etc. Nevertheless, it is more usual to use a *generic term* or the *particular name*; one possibility is using the name that's indicated near the piece of food you have in mind; otherwise you can ask the employee for the name, there is no problem.

You  use more readily the pronoun "ceux-ci" when you choose certain pieces rather than others; that presupposes that you are able to make the difference, that you can see all that is being proposed, etc.

- — Je voudrais un blanc de poulet.
  — Bien cuit, ou cuit à point ?
  — Donnez-moi l'un de ceux-ci,  bien cuit (s'il vous plait). _ *or just as well*:  Donnez-m'en un bien cuit, (s'il vous plait) (*without choosing*). _ *and simpler*:  Un bien cuit (s'il vous plait).

*generic names*: pâtisserie, pain, petit pain, dessert, plat, hors-d'œuvre, sandwich, …

If what you want is named by a mass noun, you can say "Est-ce que je pourrais avoir **une portion** de ceci ?". You can also use the word "plat" if what you want is a prepared dish.

- Je voudrais une (ou deux, trois, etc.) portions de ce **plat**. (*In almost all cases you have to point to the dish with your hand, but that goes without saying and is not particular to French I should say.)

*or*

- Est-ce que je pourrais avoir une (ou deux, trois, etc.) portion(s) de ce **plat**.

If the food has already been put onto dishes or into tubs you can say "Un de ces plats" and "une de ces barquettes (tub)"

You can say "Est-ce que je peux en avoir un ?" practically only when you first had a little talk with the employee so as to know better what you are going to buy or when you just asked for the name; in that case "Est-ce que je peux en avoir un ?" is perfect (remember the name of the thing must be countable, though).

"Est-ce que je pourrais un peu de cela/ceci" is not correct; "pouvoir", as in English, is always constructed with another verb.